# Substract 2 hours from datetime on Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on Snowflake, need to substract 2 hours from specifc date:

date time: 2021-06-10 14:07:04.848 -0400

'2021-06-10 14:07:04.848 -0400'  - 2 hours

expected result: 2021-06-10 12:07:04.848 -0400  (now it's twelve o'clock).

Datediff didn't work:

```
DATEDIFF(hour,2,TO_DATE(substr(p.insertedon,1,10)))
```

There is any simple way to do this? just a subtraction of 2 hours to date time
Regards

Comment: substr(p.insertedon,1,10) only returns the date portion of the string - with no time. Try fixing that part of the SQL first. Also, why are you holding timestamps as strings (I assume that's what you are doing, based on your code)?

Comment: You might try TO_TIMESTAMP instead of TO_DATE as well.
I usually troubleshoot by spitting out each part
`SELECT substr(...), TO_DATE(substr(...)), DATEDIFF(...TO_DATE(substr(...))`
That way you can see where it's breaking down

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `INTERVAL`:

```
SELECT p.insertedon - INTERVAL '2 HOURS'
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select DATEADD(HOUR,-2,try_to_timestamp('2021-06-10 14:07:04.848') )

or 

select DATEADD(HOUR,-TimeDiffHoursColumn,try_to_timestamp('2021-06-10 14:07:04.848') )
```

INTERVAL will be difficult to use if you are subtracting a dynamic hours from a column.